# Removing consecutive numbers from a sequence in XQuery

Tags: functional-programming, xquery, esb, osb

**XQuery**

**Input**: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27,28)

**Output**: (1,7,14,17,24,28)

I tried to remove consecutive numbers from the input sequence using the XQuery functions but failed doing so

```
    xquery version "1.0" encoding "utf-8";

    declare namespace ns1="http://www.somenamespace.org/types";

    declare variable $request as xs:integer* external;

    declare function local:func($reqSequence as xs:integer*) as xs:integer* {

    let $nonRepeatSeq := for $count in (1 to count($reqSequence)) return
                          if ($reqSequence[$count+1] - $reqSequence) then
                          remove($reqSequence,$count+1)
                          else ()
    return
    $nonRepeatSeq
    };

    local:func((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27,28))
```

Please suggest how to do so in XQuery functional language.

Comment: Always provide a _specific problem statement_, describe where you are stuck. "failed" is not a reasonable problem description, do you receive an error message, do you get wrong output, ...?

Comment: Simple stuck at functional stateless part..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simple ways to do this in XQuery.  Both rely on being able to assign the sequence of values to a variable, so that we can look at pairs of individual members of it when we need to.

First, just iterate over the values and select (a) the first value, (b) any value which is not one greater than its predecessor, and (c) any value which is not one less than its successor.  [OP points out that the last value also needs to be included; left as an exercise for the reader.  Or see Michael Kay's answer, which provides a terser formulation of the filter; DeMorgan's Law strikes again!]

```
let $vseq := (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27,28)
for $v at $pos in $vseq
return if ($pos eq 1
           or $vseq[$pos - 1] ne $v - 1
           or $vseq[$pos + 1] ne $v + 1)
       then $v 
       else ()
```

Or, second, do roughly the same thing in a filter expression:

```
let $vseq := (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27,28)
return $vseq[
    for $i in position() return 
        $i eq 1 
        or . ne $vseq[$i - 1] + 1 
        or . ne $vseq[$i + 1] - 1]
```

The primary difference between these two ways of performing the calculation and your non-working attempt is that they don't say anything about changing or modifying the sequence; they simply specify a new sequence.  By using a filter expression, the second formulation makes explicit that the result will be a subsequence of $vseq; the `for` expression makes no such guarantee in general (although because for each value it returns either the empty sequence or the value itself, we can see that here too the result will be a subsequence:  a copy of $vseq from which some values have been omitted.

Many programmers find it difficult to stop thinking in terms of assignment to variables or modification of data structures, but its worth some effort.

[Addendum] I may be overlooking something, but I don't see a way to express this calculation in pure XPath 2.0, since XPath 2.0 seems not to have any mechanism that can bind a variable like `$vseq` to a non-singleton sequence of values. (XPath 3.0 has `let` expressions, so it's not a challenge there.  The second formulation above is itself pure XPath 3.0.)

Comment: Yes it works but it removes the last number as well which we don't want as it ends the sequence there and no numbers are after that thus in not a continuous number

Comment: However just added the last number to the sequence

Comment: Michael, you can do it in XPath 2.0 provided the input sequence is supplied externally as a parameter, or if it's actually derived from the content of an XML document: see my solution.

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, quite right; I was regarding the external binding of the variable as not being "in pure XPath 2.0".

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT this can be done as:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$in" group-adjacent=". - position()">
  <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[1], current-group()[last()]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In XQuery 3.0 you can do it with tumbling windows, but I'm too lazy to work out the detail.

An XPath 2.0 solution (assuming the input sequence is in `$in`) is:

```
for $i in 1 to count($in) 
return $in[$i][not(. eq $in[$i - 1]+1 and . eq $in[$i+1]-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several logic and XQuery usage errors in your solution, but the main problem with it is that variables in XQuery are immutable, so you cannot reassign a value to one once assigned. Therefore, it's often easier to think about these types of problems in terms of recursive solutions:

```
declare function local:non-consec(
  $prev as xs:integer?,
  $rest as xs:integer*
) as xs:integer*
{
  if (empty($rest)) then ()
  else 
    let $curr := head($rest)
    let $next := subsequence($rest, 2, 1)
    return (
      if ($prev eq $curr - 1 and $curr eq $next - 1)
      then () (: This number is part of a consecutive sequence :)
      else $curr,
      local:non-consec(head($rest), tail($rest))
    )
};

local:non-consec((), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27,28))
=>
1
7
14
17
24
28
```

Comment: Using XQuery version 1 where head and tail functions are not implemented internally

Comment: @KaushikBose For XQuery 1 compatibility you can simply replace `head($rest)` with `$rest[1]` and `tail($rest)` with `subsequence($rest, 2)`.